# Outlook displaying links beside text instead of making link clickable

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, templates, mail-rule

For some reason, all outgoing messages that are sent via a mailboxrule using a template, shows links inside angle brackets beside the text that is supposed to be clickable.
It should look like this:

Hello [this](https://google.com) is a link.

But instead, it looks like this:

Hello this <https://google.com > is a link.

You can see the difference here:

[Template being sent normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PfHq.png)

[Template being sent with mailbox rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH9Xm.png)

The mailbox rule is configured as followed:  (It is translated from Dutch so the words might not match 100%)

- Apply this rule after the message is received
- And has the category "x"
- Answer the message with "Path to template location"

It seems that the entire mail is being changed as font, when sending it using the mailbox rule.

I've tried reinstalling Outlook.
The user that has the issue is using Outlook 2016. The same issue persists in Outlook 2019.
It seems that it is related to the users domain profile. When i created a new AD user, logged on to the same PC, using the same version of Outlook, adding the same mailboxes, using the same mailbox rule and template. The problem doesn't occur. Nor does it work when he tries it on a different PC, where I know the template is being sent correctly.

By default the mailbox rule is disabled and the rule is being executed manually.
The user needs to reply to multiple people that sent an apply form. The way we answer to all these people in one go, is by using the mailbox rule. Is there another way to send mail to different recipients? This needs to be done in a way that the receiver cannot see the different recipients. Replying manually to all these apply forms takes too much time.

Comment: im not positive this is the issue, but if you go, File > Options > Mail What is the option "compose message in this format" set to?

Comment: Is set to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in my environment and found a strange situation, it seems that this issue may be related to the email you received, just for your reference:

Using Outlook 2016, email account A to receive messages

Sent messages from another account B in different versions of Outlook client to account A

Email account A with Outlook rule sent two different messages(one is normal and the other displays links beside text)